# SSMS export error: column names not unique? And, how do I exclude joined field from output?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssms

I am running the following query and encountering two problems.

First, attempting to use [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/202/simple-way-to-export-data-from-sql-server/) method yields an error message `There is more than one data source column with the name "Item_ID". The data source column names must be unique.`

Second, the second `Item_ID` is being populated in to the grid when I run the query. Is there any method by which I can hide this second instance? I imagine this is related to the `INNER JOIN` of the table `2014` with itself.

My main goal is to easily export this information to Excel from SSMS. Apparently the data returned is too large to copy/paste from the clipboard.

```
SELECT * FROM [2014] AS e
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT r.Item_ID 
            FROM [2014] AS r 
            WHERE r.R_Num = 7 AND r.QUAL = 'T') AS m
ON e.Item_ID = m.Item_ID
WHERE e.[P/S_Num] = 0000 AND 
      e.R_Num = 9 AND (e.S_Type = 'S' AND 
      (e.Wgt >= 538196000) OR (e.S_Type = 'A' AND e.Wgt >= 12355))
```

Comment: dont use `*` in your select statement, spell out the columns you want, using table aliases. This will solve both issues. or at a minimum use `e.*`, but still not a great idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is use of `*` in your query select list `SELECT * FROM [2014] AS e`. Explicitly specify the column(s) you are trying to fetch and qualify it with the specific table alias/table name from where you want it in that case like below; which will fetch only the columns `column1, column2 and column3`

```
SELECT e.column1, e.column2, e.column3 FROM [2014] AS e
```

If you don't want to include `Item_ID` then remove it from your select list (OR) include the specific one you are trying to select like

```
select e.Item_ID, .... FROM [2014] AS e
```

Comment: OP wants `e.Item_ID` and not `m.Item_ID`

Comment: @DanielE., Ahh!! ok; Thank for pointing that but sole point of concern here is, using the specific column and qualify it with proper table alias.

Comment: Didn't mean to sound snippy, just wanted to make as clear as possible for OP.

Comment: @DanielE., NO, you did right by bringing that point and I do appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately the table has hundreds of fields, so listing them all by name is rather cumbersome. Also, I still do not understand why m.Item_ID is being pulled into the query. After doing further testing, it appears that it may be r.Item_ID that is being populated. So, my questions would be: how do I eliminate this from my result?

Comment: @Addikt, there is no automatic way of eliminating it other than explicitly specifying the columns you want to get as I had already pointed in answer. Yes, to shorten it further you can say like `select e.*, m.some_col, r.other_col from [2014] AS e ...`

Comment: Still encountering errors attempting to export from the database, but it seems that adding `e.*` has solved the duplicate field issue. Very helpful. Thanks!